# Intel pin: getting instruction memory write\read size

Tags: intel-pin

I am trying to change a bit the [Memory Reference Trace (Instruction Instrumentation)](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97438/Pin/html/index.html#MAddressTrace) example from the pin documentation.

My goal is to extract from each instruction that access memory also the size of the size of the memory to read\write in bytes.

I looked in the documentation and found that I need to use

```
IARG_MEMORYREAD_SIZE
IARG_MEMORYWRITE_SIZE
```

to hold that size.

I couldn't find though in the documentation how to extract this data from the instruction.

here is my code:

```
for (UINT32 memOp = 0; memOp < memOperands; memOp++)
{
    if (INS_MemoryOperandIsRead(ins, memOp))
    {
        if(INS_hasKnownMemorySize(ins))
        {
            //IARG_MEMORYREAD_SIZE  memReadSize = what to do here?

            INS_InsertPredicatedCall(
                ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)MyFuncWhenRead,
                IARG_INST_PTR,
                IARG_MEMORYOP_EA, memOp,
                IARG_END);
        }
    }

    if (INS_MemoryOperandIsWritten(ins, memOp))
    {
        if(INS_hasKnownMemorySize(ins))
        {
            //IARG_MEMORYREAD_SIZE  memWriteSize = what to do here?

            INS_InsertPredicatedCall(
                ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)MyFuncWhenWrite,
                IARG_INST_PTR,
                IARG_MEMORYOP_EA, memOp,
                IARG_END);
        }
    }
}
```

Would appreciate some help solving this.
That is, what to write in the line with the comment

```
        //IARG_MEMORYREAD_SIZE  memReadSize = ???
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As a quick reminder (this is an important concept in PIN, often overlooked):

Conceptually, instrumentation consists of two components:

- A mechanism that decides where and what code is inserted: the **instrumentation**.
- The code to execute at insertion points: the **analysis**.

The `INS_INSERT(xxx)CALL` functions are used in the instrumentation routine (to tell to the analysis routine) when and what code is inserted. So, in your code:

```
        INS_InsertPredicatedCall(
            ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)MyFuncWhenRead,
            IARG_INST_PTR,
            IARG_MEMORYOP_EA, memOp,
            IARG_END);
```

- `IPOINT_BEFORE` is the **when**.

  - It tells where the analysis routine is inserted relative to the instrumented code (here, the insertion point is made before the instruction).
- `IARG_INST_PTR`, `IARG_MEMORYOP_EA` are the **what**.

  - They determine the arguments that are passed to the analysis routine.
  - They are received by the analysis routine in the order they are declared.
- `MyFuncWhenRead` is the **analysis** routine called by the instrumentation.

If you have something that starts with `IARG_`it is an [IARG_TYPE](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97503/Pin/html/group__INST__ARGS.html#ga089c27ca15e9ff139dd3a3f8a6f8451d) which is has to passed to the `INS_Insert(xxx)Call` function.

The documentation for `IARG_MEMORYREAD_SIZE` says:

> IARG_MEMORYREAD_SIZE Type: UINT32. Size in bytes of memory read. (...)

The `Type` tells us what the **analysis** routine receives.

In your case you have (in this **precise** order):

- `IARG_INST_PTR`: Type: ADDRINT
- `IARG_MEMORYOP_EA`: Type: ADDRINT
- `IARG_MEMORYREAD_SIZE`: Type: UINT32

Which means your instrumentation function will look like this:

```
    INS_InsertPredicatedCall(
        ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)MyFuncWhenRead,
        IARG_INST_PTR,
        IARG_MEMORYOP_EA, memOp,
        IARG_MEMORYREAD_SIZE,
        IARG_END);
```

And your analysis function should look like this:

```
VOID MyFuncWhenRead(
    ADDRINT ins_ptr, // from IARG_INST_PTR (address of the instruction)
    ADDRINT mem_op_addr, // from IARG_MEMORYOP_EA (address of the memory read)
    UINT32 mem_read_size, // from IARG_MEMORYREAD_SIZE (size of the read)
) 
{ 
    // ...
}
```

The same logic applies to `IARG_MEMORYWRITE_SIZE`.